# How to use multiple data types, with an ADT defined by me

Tags: c, abstract-data-type

I have defined a simple C API that manages a doubly linked list with a Data type, defined at a header file, acompanied with its functions (in example: print_data, compare, etc.).

This way it is easy for me to use it easily into any project I need.
But what if I want to use this ADT *into the same project* but with **different data**?

The ADT is defined as this at its header file:

```
typedef struct DoublyLinkedList_ADT *dllistptr;
```

And at it source file there are these two structs:

```
struct DoublyLinkedListNode
{
    dllnodeptr previous, next;
    Data data;
};
struct DoublyLinkedList_ADT
{
    dllnodeptr head, tail;
    int size;
};
```

And at the data header file there is this:

```
typedef struct Data_type
    {
        int num;
    }Data;
```

So that I can define Data into anything I want.

Is there any way to achieve this?

---

The only one that I've come up is to copy paste the code adding a "_OtherData" to all "Data" references. But this doesn't sound that good.

After reading some other questions, I've seen that there is an implementation that needs a `void*` definintion of Data and each time I use it, I must cast to the right data type.

Is there anything easier/faster?